# Dockerizing an SSH daemon service

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I'm having trouble dockerizing an SSH service alongside the jupyter/all-spark-notebook image.

Below is my config:

Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest

ARG PASS

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo "root:$PASS" | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/\#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

RUN service ssh start

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  spark:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        PASS: ${PASS:-pass}
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '8888:8888/tcp'
      - '4040:4040/tcp'
      - '2222:22'
    working_dir: /home/user/all-spark-notebook
    user: root
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - /home/all-spark-notebook:/home/user/all-spark-notebook
```

.env

```
PASS=password
CHOWN_HOME='yes'
GRANT_SUDO='yes'
CHOWN_HOME_OPTS='-R'
NB_UID=1000
NB_GID=1000
NB_USER=user
NB_GROUP=user
```

I'm facing a couple of problems:

1. I can't seem to pass the password variable from .env so that it is set via chpasswd. Not sure if I'm handling arg/env variables the correct way.
2. If I don't use an arg password like the above. I can get around issue (1). And the container starts up fine. But I still can't SSH into it. I actually need to attach and manually run "/usr/sbin/sshd" from the console. If I do that, than I can SSH in without any issue.

Ideas?

Comment: The .env file is ignored while building an image. It's only used during container startup when docker-compose is interpreting the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I'm passing it directly using args?

Comment: My bad, didn't see that.